# Textmate - don't even use soft tabs

Tags: tabs, textmate

I've just moved to Mac and am trying out TextMate, so I'm not familiar with bundle config etc. Is there a way to make TextMate just use spaces, rather than soft tabs, for all file types?

For example: I type 5 spaces. I want to then be able to go back three spaces and insert more characters, so I have [two spaces][text][three spaces]. What happens instead is that I hit the left arrow twice and end up back at the start of the line; even though there are no tab characters in the underlying file, TextMate it treating the first 4 spaces as a logical tab. I want to turn that off, globally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first answer doesn't exactly solve your problem but perhaps you could consider it. You can turn down the soft tab spacing to 2 spaces to be able to do what you mentioned in that example. Unless you have a very complicated spacing scheme, I find that 2 spaces gives the best compromise between nicely indented code and control over text placement. This setting would hold for each other language that you don't manually set the soft tabs for.

[image: TextMate with Soft Tab size 2]

If you really want no soft tabs at all, the method would be to set a soft tab size of 1, which is not possible in the TextMate GUI. This can be done by modifying the TextMate plist file at the Terminal. You'll need to set that for each language separately. As an example, for Perl:

```
defaults write com.macromates.textmate OakTextViewScopedTabSize -dict-add 'source.perl' '{ tabSize = 1; }'
```

Replace `source.perl` with whatever language you want to use; `tabSize = 1` refers to the soft tab size. If it's for plain text, replace `source.perl` with `text.plain`. Looking at the `com.macromates.textmate` plist file, there also seem to be the entries `text.catch-all` and `source.catch-all` which I would assume would work for everything that hasn't already been specified. But it didn't seem that way when I tested.

Comment: Looks cracking. I'll have a go at that this evening, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

to enable SOFT TABS

> defaults write com.macromates.textmate  OakTextViewScopedSoftTabs
>   -dict-add 'source.perl' '{ softTabs = 1; }'

you can list all existent:

> defaults read com.macromates.textmate  OakTextViewScopedSoftTabs